# Firebase Version: 8.1.0 is lower than the minimum version (9.0.0) required for google-services plugin

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I need to add push notification to my app in android but when I add

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I got this error

```
Error:(75, 0) Version: 8.1.0 is lower than the minimum version (9.0.0) required for google-services plugin.
```

This is my **bulld.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 25
        versionName "2.4"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }) 
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.3'
    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.twotoasters.jazzylistview:library:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.twotoasters.jazzylistview:library-recyclerview:1.2.1'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.0'
    compile 'me.nlmartian.silkcal:library:0.1.1'
    compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.1.0'
    compile 'com.pushbots:pushbots-lib:2.0.13@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.1.0'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

-

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

I tried to solve this with many solution but I can't , so if anyone can help me please answer!

Comment: You're compiling way too many dependencies. And few are very outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to update your play service as required by firebase so use any version above or equal to `9.0.0`

so replace this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
```

with this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.6'
```

and sync your project

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. >
>   File google-services.json is missing.

Get a config file for your Android app
To download a config file for an Android app:

Follow below steps

- Sign in to Firebase and open your project.
- Click the Settings icon and select Project settings.
- In the Your apps card, select the package name of the app you need a config file for from the list.
- Click google-services.json.

and copy `google-services.json` file and paste it into yours Projects's `app` folder

Comment: thank you ,, after i add this and sync the project i got this error

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
   Searched Location:

Comment: you need to download `google-services.json ` file from firebase projects settings  and add it to your project's `app` folder because this file contains vital information for verification by firebase

Comment: Check the integration tutorial. You've probably missed some steps.
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Check your **build.gradle** and change this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
```

to this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.6'
```

Or even better - **remove this import** if the only thing you need is Firebase Cloud Messaging.